# Como parsear json a objetos de clases en java?

Tags: java, json, json-lib

estoy tratando de consumir una api con java utilizo la libreria de httpClient de apache, me consume bien y me muestra el resultado y JSON todo bien hasta allí, ahora la cuestion es que tengo una clase con los atributos y al tratar de obtener los datos para hacer el castin me genera un error y no se como solucionar,
aqui el codigo java:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:50760/api/BockChapters");

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

        // Create a custom response handler
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {

            @Override
            public String handleResponse(
                    final HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
                } else {
                    throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
                }
            }

        };

        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(responseBody);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //manejo de error
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //manejo de error
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //manejo de error
    } finally {
        try {
            httpclient.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JSON.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

este es el resultado:

```
[{"Numbre":1,"Title":"Hola Mundo1","Pages":222},{"Numbre":2,"Title":"Hola Mundo2","Pages":222},{"Numbre":3,"Title":"Hola Mundo3","Pages":222},{"Numbre":4,"Title":"Hola Mundo4","Pages":222},{"Numbre":5,"Title":"Hola Mundo5","Pages":222},{"Numbre":6,"Title":"Hola Mundo6","Pages":222},{"Numbre":7,"Title":"Hola Mundo7","Pages":222},{"Numbre":8,"Title":"Hola Mundo8","Pages":222}]
```

la clase a la que quiero hacer el castin es esta

```
private int Numbre;

public String Title;

public int Pages;

public BockChapter() {
}

public BockChapter(int Numbre, String Title, int Pages) {
    this.Numbre = Numbre;
    this.Title = Title;
    this.Pages = Pages;
}
```

e tratado de hacer el casting utilizando una libreria de JSON se llama json-simple lo hago de esta forma

```
JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parse.parse(responseBody);
        JSONObject objson = (JSONObject) obj;
        String blog = (String) objson.get("Title");
        System.out.println(blog);
```

el error que me arroja es el siguiente

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to net.sf.json.JSONObject
```

y el error hace referencia a la linea

```
JSONObject objson = (JSONObject) obj;
```

alguien me podría decir como solucionar este error o que otra forma se podría hacer

Comment: hola guiado por el paquete de tu error he agregado la etiqueta json-lib ya que parece que tu codigo la usa. esperemos que atraiga un poco mas de atencion

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tienes un POJO como el siguiente

```
public class Persona {

    private String nombre;

    private String edad;

    //getters
    //setters
}
```

Podrías utilizar [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) parte de [jackson](/questions/tagged/jackson)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String respuesta = "{"nombre": "nombre", "edad": 99}";
Persona persona = mapper.readValue(respuesta, Persona.class);

String respuesta = "[{"nombre": "nombre", "edad": 99}]";
List<Persona> personas = mapper.readValue(respuesta, new TypeReference<List<Persona>>(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo para el tratamiento de json uso **com.fasterxml.jackson**, que es parte de [jackson](/questions/tagged/jackson).

En tu caso el POJO quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class BockChapter {
    
    @JsonProperty(value = "Numbre")
    private int number;
    
    @JsonProperty(value = "Title")
    private String title;
    
    @JsonProperty(value = "Pages")
    private int pages;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(int pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Libro [number=" + number + ", title=" + title + ", pages=" + pages + "]";
    }   
}
```

He añadido la anotación **@JsonProperty** para que los nombres de los campos cumplan los estándares en java.

El código para parsear la respuesta en un array de objetos es el siguiente:

```
String response = "[{\"Numbre\":1,\"Title\":\"Hola Mundo1\",\"Pages\":222},{\"Numbre\":2,\"Title\":\"Hola Mundo2\",\"Pages\":222},{\"Numbre\":3,\"Title\":\"Hola Mundo3\",\"Pages\":222}]";
    
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        try {
            List<BockChapter> libros = mapper.readValue(response, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, BockChapter.class));
            System.out.println(libros);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

En este caso, al ser una lista, tenemos que especificar el tipo de colección al que queremos parsear la respuesta.

Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que lo que estás obteniendo es un Array (JSONArray) y eso no puede ser convertido a JSONObject. Así que intenta convertirlo a JSONArray y manejas la información con los métodos que esa clase te provea.  Puedes intentar lo se menciona [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440098/org-json-simple-jsonarray-cannot-be-cast-to-org-json-simple-jsonobject) y quizá ver más información:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj  = parser.parse(content);
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add(obj);
```

Comment: me genera un error en la linea JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

Comment: ¿qué dice el error?

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de obtener los datos seria de la siguiente forma:

Libreria [gson](/questions/tagged/gson):

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Github:
https://github.com/google/gson

Documentación:
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

```
*
 //Json de tu web service
        String json = "[{\"Numbre\":1,\"Title\":\"Hola Mundo1\",\"Pages\":222},{\"Numbre\":2,\"Title\":\"Hola Mundo2\",\"Pages\":222},{\"Numbre\":3,\"Title\":\"Hola Mundo3\",\"Pages\":222},{\"Numbre\":4,\"Title\":\"Hola Mundo4\",\"Pages\":222},{\"Numbre\":5,\"Title\":\"Hola Mundo5\",\"Pages\":222},{\"Numbre\":6,\"Title\":\"Hola Mundo6\",\"Pages\":222},{\"Numbre\":7,\"Title\":\"Hola Mundo7\",\"Pages\":222},{\"Numbre\":8,\"Title\":\"Hola Mundo8\",\"Pages\":222}]";




//Json parser | JsonElements
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        //Parsear el json string a JsonObject, a JsonArray, a JsonPrimitive o a JsonNull
        JsonElement element = jsonParser.parse(json);
        //verificamos si es un json array
        if (element.isJsonArray())
        {
            //parseamos el elemento a json array
            JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
            //lista de tipo objeto para almacenar tus valores
            List<BockChapter> bockChapters = new ArrayList<>();
            //recorremos el json array
            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.size();i++)
            {
                //obtenemos los objetos de la posición i
                JsonObject  objectJ = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                //modelo para asignar tus valores
                BockChapter object = new BockChapter();
                //Obtenemos los valores
                object.setNumber(objectJ.get("Numbre").getAsString());
                object.setTitle(objectJ.get("Title").getAsString());
                object.setPages(objectJ.get("Pages").getAsInt());
                //agregamos a la lista
                bockChapters.add(object);
            }
            //verificamos la cantidad de registros obtenidos y agregados a la lista
            Log.e("List<BockChapter>: ","=> "+ bockChapters.size());
        }
```

O bien:

```
try {
            //Recibimos el JSON Array
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
            //Recorremos el Array
            for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++)
            {
                //Obtenermos los objetos de la posición i
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                BockChapter bockChapter = new BockChapter();
                //Obtenemos los valores del objeto en la posición indicada
                bockChapter.setNumber(object.getString("Numbre"));
                bockChapter.setTitle(object.getString("Title"));
                bockChapter.setPages(object.getInt("Pages"));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

¿Como identificar un JSONArray de un JSONObject?
Te dejo la siguiente imagén para que detectes cuando es un JSON array o un JSON object.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]